# Error in checking permission granted or not in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
val permission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
```

This line throws me error on the word **permission** and android studio is not able to identify the keyword.

What has possibly gone wrong?

I was following this tutorial [here](https://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Kotlin_-_Making_Runtime_Permission_Requests_in_Android)

Comment: Check if your import has `import android.Manifest`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your import statement is correct, should be:

```
import android.Manifest
```